# Remove all Customers in Magento

Tags: sql, magento

I need remove all clients from my Magento install, because they have bad dates. I have 70,000 customers in my developed site. How can I do this with SQL?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Make a **BACKUP** and test on a dev server first! **This will DELETE all customer data including logs.**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- reset customers
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_datetime;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_decimal;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_int;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_text;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_varchar;
TRUNCATE customer_entity;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_datetime;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_decimal;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_int;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_text;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_varchar;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;

ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_datetime AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_decimal AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_int AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_text AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_varchar AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_datetime AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_decimal AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_int AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_text AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_varchar AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE log_customer AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE log_visitor AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE log_visitor_info AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Magento's table structure is subject to change and could be affected by extensions. I'd advice caution when doing this on newer versions of magento.

Comment: I got an error in MySQL running the above queries: `Invalid default value for 'created_at'`. It can be solved adding this line at the start: `/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;` (more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23147829/3763649)

Comment: Note: if using phpmyadmin 4.6+ you can remove the 'set foreign_key_checks=' statements and simply uncheck the 'enable foreign key check' box in the SQL section.

Answer (score 14):

```
Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);

$customers = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection();

foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    $customer->delete();
}
```

Be sure to know what you are doing though.. You can disable the customer as well if delete is not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Or you just build a shell script and do something like that (not fast, but it is clean):

```
 /*
 * Starter
 * */
public function run()
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M');
    if (!$this->getArg('iknowwhatido') || $this->getArg('iknowwhatido') != 'yes') {
        $this->usageHelp();
        echo "DEACTIVATED (call it with param '-iknowwhatido yes' to make it work!) \n";
        return -1;
    }
    Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
    $customers = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()->delete();
}
```